# Stream from response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync() is not readable randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, httpcontent, httpresponsemessage

I am making a .Net Web API application in which the following code is making call to my different c# application to download file and then save it on the disk. Sometimes everything works fine and I get the file but sometimes the below code is not able to read the stream and I can see the remote connection closed exception in my other application.

```
public async Task<string> GetFilePathAsync(TestModel model)
{
    string filePath = string.Empty;
    var response = await cgRequestHelper.DownloadAsync(model);  

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {                    
        filePath = await SaveCgStreamAsync(cgResponse, serviceModel.FileName);
    }
    return filePath;
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadAsync(TestModel model)
{            
    if (model == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Url))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Url");
    if (model.Headers == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Headers");

    HttpResponseMessage response;
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        foreach (var header in model.Headers)
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }
        response = await httpClient.GetAsync(model.Url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead); 
    }
    return response;            
}        

public async Task<string> SaveCgStreamAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, string fileName)
{
    if (response == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("response");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

    var filePath = _CreateTemporaryLocation(fileName);
    Stream cgStream = null;
    Stream fileStream = null;
    try
    {
        cgStream =  await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        await cgStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(cgStream != null)
            cgStream.Dispose();
        if(fileStream != null)
            fileStream.Dispose();
    }

    return filePath;            
}
```

I have set ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000 in Global.asax.cs

In my current application I am getting exception on "await cgStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);" line when it tries to read the cgStream. The exception is "Cannot access a closed Stream." with null InnerException
The other application exception is:
System.Web.HttpException: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800703E3.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)

On an average, 1 out of 10 request is failing with the above error. Since it is random and not always failing, it is very difficult to troubleshoot the problem.

The above code is written with the help from: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/efficiently-streaming-large-http-responses-with-httpclient

Any help related to this problem is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: _"The remote host closed the connection"_ -- the error message seems reasonably clear to me, but your question not so much. Why do you think you should be able to read from the stream if the connection has been closed? What is it about the error message you don't understand? It's also not clear from your question which end is closing the connection. Regardless, providing a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem would be critical in illustrating the issue you're asking about.

Comment: Peter, let's not unnecessarily hammer new people with the MCVE. It's obvious from his question what's going on, and the information provided is not overly complex.

Comment: Peter, If closing the connection is the root problem then I need to find out what is closing the connection randomly? 6-7 times it works then suddenly this error and then again works fine. Please let me know if you need any other details to make my question more clear to you.

Comment: Not related to your problem but you should never do `throw e;` it distroys the stack trace of the original exception. You should either be doing `throw new SomeNewExecption("Extra Info", e);` so e is the inner exception or just do `throw;` with no argument and that will re-throw the exception without modifiing it. However, in your case the catch could be removed entirelly, it is perfectly fine to have a try/finally with no catch block.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the suggestion but I have put try catch block there just to hit the break point(for debugging purpose). I have try catch in controller which can take care of everything.

Comment: In that case replace `throw e;` with `throw;` and put your breakpoint there. That way you don't mess up your stack traces.

Answer (score 9):

I figured out the problem in the code:
The problem was that I was initializing HttpClient object in 'using' and using its response outside the using scope. This will dispose the HttpClient object, hence breaking the remote connection and that is why I am not able to stream the content. The random behavior was because we do not know when will the object gets disposed, sometimes it does not gets disposed before streaming and sometimes it does.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, `Stream.CopyToAsync` is, well, asynchronous. That means it isn't going to block the caller (your method), which will go on to Dispose of the stream in the finally block. You have a race condition, in other words. Switch to `Stream.CopyTo` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hello Chris, I will try Stream.CopyTo instead but just to let you know I was trying the below code earlier and later changed that to CopyToAsync

Comment: Even if I remove the dispose of the stream from finally I still see the same issue.

Comment: It looks like you are calling some other version of the method above

Comment: Chris, I tried CopyTo instead of CopyToAsync and it did not help. Still seeing the same issue. Attaching the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uLaz.png

Comment: Peter, I have done all the corrections. Let me know if you'r still confused with the version of the methods.

Comment: If the attempt that you posted as an answer is accurate, you are still calling SaveCgStreamAsync, which doesn't do a blocking copy.

Comment: Corrected that. (That was a typo while pasting code here) I have tried lot of other scenarios but none of them is helping so far.

Answer (score 0):

I will try `Stream.CopyTo` instead but just to let you know I was trying the below code earlier and later changed that to `CopyToAsync`

```
public async Task<string> GetFilePathAsync(TestModel model)
    {
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        var response = await cgRequestHelper.DownloadAsync(model);  

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {                   
            Stream cgStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            filePath = SaveCgStream(cgStream , model.FileName);
        }
        return filePath;
    }

    public string SaveCgStream(Stream cgStream, string fileName)
        {
            if (response == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("response");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

            const int CHUNK_SIZE = 40000;
            var filePath = _CreateTemporaryLocation(fileName);
            var fileStream = File.Create(filePath, CHUNK_SIZE);

            int bytesRead;
            var buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
            bool isReadStarted = false;
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = cgStream.Read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        isReadStarted = true;
                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                } while (bytesRead > 0);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            return filePath;
        }
```

And I was getting the same error in the `bytesRead = cgStream.Read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);` line. Do you still think it is a `CopyToAsync` problem?
I doubt it because when I put a break point I can see that stream is not readable as Read property is false before even going to `CopyToAsync` method.

I tried `CopyTo` instead of `CopyToAsync` and it did not help. Screenshot:

[image]